# Bootstrap Center Checkboxes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, bootstrap-4

How can I get the check input to be vertically and horizontally centered within the parent column?

Image below shows the parent column and checkbox, I've tried `text-centered`, `d-flex justify-content-center`, `align-self-center` and none have worked. I think it has to do with the nested columns?

[image: Checkbox not centered within parent column]

```html
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-lg">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">
      <div class="row align-items-center h-100">
        <div class="col-4 d-flex border justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
          <div class="form-check align-items-center d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">  
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="{{obj.total}}" id="flexCheckDefault" checked> <!-- CENTER THIS ITEM -->
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-center h-100 border">
          <div class="form-check d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="{{obj.total}}" id="flexCheckDefault" checked> <!-- CENTER THIS ITEM -->
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 h-100 border d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
          <div class="form-check d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="{{obj.total}}" id="flexCheckDefault" checked> <!-- CENTER THIS ITEM -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-10">
      <div class="row align-items-center h-100">
        <div class="col-2 h-100 border d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
          <span>Name</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-8 h-100 border d-flex align-items-center">
          <span>Desc</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1 h-100 border d-flex align-items-center">
          <span>Total</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1 wg-right-bottom-border h-100">
          <div class="form-check d-flex justify-content-center">
            <input class="form-check-input align-self-center" type="checkbox" value="{{obj.total}}" id="flexCheckDefault">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Bonus points for it being vertically and horizontally centered while printing as well.

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. It's nonsensical as it is. See [ask].

Comment: You've tagged Bootstrap 4 but used version 5 CDN. Also, your demo doesn't seem to show the problem you describe. Please revise your post to correct and clarify.

Answer (score 1):

### Check now all the checkbox are in center position. Is it what u want..?

> I have **removed** only **.align-item-center** from all the three .**form-check** **.div** attribute and add the **.d-flex** and **.justify-content-center** in last checkbox **.col** tag.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>solution</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-lg">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">
      <div class="row h-100">
        <div class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-center h-100 border">
          <div class="form-check d-flex justify-content-center">  
            <input class="form-check-input d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" type="checkbox" value="{{obj.total}}" id="flexCheckDefault" checked> <!-- CENTER THIS ITEM -->
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-center h-100 border">
          <div class="form-check d-flex justify-content-center">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="{{obj.total}}" id="flexCheckDefault" checked> <!-- CENTER THIS ITEM -->
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-center h-100 border">
          <div class="form-check d-flex justify-content-center">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="{{obj.total}}" id="flexCheckDefault" checked> <!-- CENTER THIS ITEM -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-10">
      <div class="row align-items-center h-100">
        <div class="col-2 h-100 border d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
          <span>Name</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-8 h-100 border d-flex align-items-center">
          <span>Desc</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1 h-100 border d-flex align-items-center">
          <span>Total</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1 d-flex justify-content-center wg-right-bottom-border h-100">
          <div class="form-check d-flex justify-content-center">
            <input class="form-check-input align-self-center" type="checkbox" value="{{obj.total}}" id="flexCheckDefault">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```